# Some Combinatorial Gymnastics (Binomial Theorem for Integers)

Tags: combinatorics

There is a proof of the [Binomial Theorem using combinatorics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Combinatorial_proof).

Let a positive integer $m$ be expressed as the sum of two positive integers $p$ and $q$.

Using a combinatorial argument (no recourse to the Binomial Theorem), explain why

$m^n = (p + q)^n =\sum_{k=0}^n{\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}}p^k q^{n-k}$

is just a matter of counting.

Hint: The functional inverse image of two disjoint sets are also disjoint.

Answer (score 1):

Take your favorite set $M$ containing $m$ elements,

Given the two integers $p$ and $q$,  you can create a partition of $M$ with two subsets, $P$ and $Q$, where $P$ has $p$ elements and $Q$ has $q$ elements. So fix this partition.

Take you favorite set $N$ with $n$ elements. If $f$ is any function mapping $N$ into $M$, the partition on $M$ lifts, via inverse images, into a two set partition of $N$.

We know that the number of all functions from $N$ into $M$ is given by $m^n$. If you look at the summation in the question, as $k$ varies assume that the '$n \; choose \; k$' represents selecting the $k$ elements of $N$ that get mapped into $P$. Of course you are constructing this so that the other $n - k$ elements are getting mapped into $Q$.

To continue your combinatorial constuction, you have to specify how the $k$ and $n - k$ elements are mapped, but that count of course is precisely given by

### $p^k q^{n-k}$