# Find $x$ and $y$ such that $\binom{100}{0}+2\binom{100}{1}+4\binom{100}{2}+\cdots+2^{100}\binom{100}{100}=x^{y}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

> Find $x$ and $y$ such that
>   $$
> \binom{100}{0}+2\binom{100}{1}+4\binom{100}{2}+\cdots+2^{100}\binom{100}{100}=x^{y}
> $$

I started out by letting $n$ be a small number.

**Let $n=3$:**
$$
2^{0}\binom{3}{0}+2^{1}\binom{3}{1}+2^{2}\binom{3}{2}+2^{3}\binom{3}{3}=1(1)+2(3)+4(3)+8(1)=27=3^{3}
$$

**Let $n=4$:**
$$
2^{0}\binom{4}{0}+2^{1}\binom{4}{1}+2^{2}\binom{4}{2}+2^{3}\binom{4}{3}+2^{4}\binom{4}{4}=1(1)+2(4)+4(6)+8(4)+16(1)=81=3^{4}
$$

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use this and solve the original question. More specifically, I know the answer is $3^{n}$, but I don't know how to do a combinatorial proof.

Comment: According to the binomial theorem, this is $(2+1)^{100}.$

Comment: Another useful question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1238516/combinatorial-proof-of-an-instance-of-the-binomial-theorem

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is the binomial theorem:

$$3^n = (2+1)^n = \sum \binom{n}{k} 2^k 1^{n-k} = \sum 2^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}$$

The combinatorics here is that when expanding $(2+1)^n$ you will get terms of the form $\prod a_j$ where $a_j$ is selected from $2, 1$, the factor $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways you can put $2$ in $k$ of the $n$ factors of the product (leaving $1$ in the rest of the factors).

Note however that this solution is not unique. We certainly have that the sum is $3^{100}$ and since $3$ is a prime that's the prime number factorization which is unique. Now if $x^{y} = 3^{100}$ we have that we can prime factor $x$ as $\prod p_j^{n_j}$ which makes $x^{y} = \prod p_j^{n_jy}$ which must be $3^{100}$ so we have that the only $p_j$ must be $3$ and $n_j y = 100$. So the solutios are given by $x = 3^j$, $y = 100/j$ for every $j\mid 100$.

Since $100=2\times2\times5\times5$ we again have some combinatorics here since iff $j\mid 100$ we have $j=2^p5^q$ where $p, q\in\{0,1,2\}$. The number of ways to select $p$ and $q$ are $3\times 3$ that is there are 9 solutions to the problem.